# Change screen without a click event using navigation stack react native

Tags: react-native

Well what I'm trying to do is when he finishes reading the qr code is to move to the next screen as soon as this event ends. I tried to do this by declaring:

```
const handleBarCodeScanned = ({ type, data }) => {
    {this.props.navigation.navigate ('testScreen', {data1, data2})}
}
```

Usually, the documentation always shows accompanied by an `onClick ()` function associated with a button.

[image]

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Button, PermissionsAndroid } from 'react-native';
import { BarCodeScanner } from 'expo-barcode-scanner';
import wifi from 'react-native-android-wifi';

export default function QrCodeScreen() {
    const [hasPermission, setHasPermission] = useState(null);
    const [scanned, setScanned] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        (async () => {
        const { status } = await BarCodeScanner.requestPermissionsAsync();
         setHasPermission(status === 'granted');
        })();
    }, []);

   const handleBarCodeScanned = ({ type, data }) => {
{this.props.navigation.navigate('nextScreen', { data1, data2 })}//Change screen


})}

   };

    if (hasPermission === null) {
        return <Text>Requesting for camera permission</Text>;
 }
    if (hasPermission === false) {
        return <Text>No access to camera</Text>;
 }

   return (
      <View
         style={{
         flex: 1,
         flexDirection: 'column',
         justifyContent: 'flex-end',
        }}>
     <BarCodeScanner
         onBarCodeScanned={scanned ? undefined : handleBarCodeScanned}
         style={StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject}
            />

  {scanned && <Button title={'Tap to Scan Again'} onPress={() => setScanned(false)} />}
</View>
```

);
}

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're using functional components so there is no this context.

You forget to import and init the navigation hook

```
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
```

And

```
export default function QrCodeScreen() {
   const navigation = useNavigation();
   ...
```

Then

```
const handleBarCodeScanned = ({ type, data }) => {
    navigation.navigate('nextScreen', { data1, data2 })
})}
```

Comment: What's not working ? What's the error ? Are you using functional or class components ? Rest of your code ? Without infos i can't help...

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the error by passing as the navigation parameter in the function declaration.

Before

```
export default function QrCodeScreen() {
}
```

After

```
export default function QrCodeScreen({navigation}) {
}
```

Change screen

```
navigation.navigate('SetupConnectionScreen');
```